# How to setup OpenMP to use whole hyperthreads for parallel processing?

Tags: linux, parallel-processing, openmp

Please help me, I want to use OpenMP for parallel-processing in my program with all threads. I set up it the same follow:

```
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
       omp_set_num_threads(272);
       region my_routine processing;
    }
```

When I execute it, I use compiler "top" to check the performance of CPU use, and just sometimes it archives 6800% (almost it less than 5500%) - it is not stable. I want it stable (always archives 6800%) during the time my program executing.

Where is being wrong for using OpenMP or we have any other method for use whole threads?

Thanks a lot.

This is my platform:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                272
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-271
Thread(s) per core:    4
Core(s) per socket:    68
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          2
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 87
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon Phi(TM) CPU 7250 @ 1.40GHz
Stepping:              1
CPU MHz:               1392.507
BogoMIPS:              2799.81
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              1024K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-271
NUMA node1 CPU(s):
```

Comment: Have you tried setting omp_places = threads , assuming that your OpenMP supports this or some proprietary equivalent?   You would try also omp_places = threads , setting various numbers of threads up to number of cores.  For most applications, this will improve performance, although not pegging your thread usage meter.

Comment: Calling omp_set_num_threadshas inside a parallel region no effect on the number of threads in that parallel region. *BUT* Reasonable OpenMP implementations will use all available threads by default anyway, so just remove the omp_set_num_threads call. You can call omp_get_num_threads() inside the parallel region  to see how many you are using. As to whether they're usefully used, that's a property of your code.

Comment: Thank tim18 and Jim Cownie, I tried with you guide but it also cannt use full threads.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 0:** safety first:
check with your Cluster-provider HPC-support team, if they do not consider harmful to set such high-level of workloads on their owned/operated Cluster device(s).

**Step 1:** set for a "smoke-on" flight-test
prepare **`lstopo`** command ( `apt-get` or require your admin to fix this, if necessary ) and create the system's NUMA-topology map into a pdf-file and post it here
prepare **`htop`** command ( `apt-get` or require your admin to fix this, if necessary ) ,
configure <kbd>F2</kbd>
Setup `METERS` to show `CPUs (1&2/4): first half in 2 shorter columns` to the left `MONITOR` panel,
setup `METERS` to show `CPUs (3&4/4): second half in 2 shorter columns` to the left `MONITOR` panel,
setup `COLUMNS` to show at least the `{ PPID, PID, TGID, CPU, CPU%, STATUS, command }` column fields

**Step 2:** with `htop`-monitor running, run the compiled OpenMP code

Expect something above this on the terminal CLI, yet the **`htop`**-monitor will show the NUMA-CPU-workloads' live-scene landscape better, than any single number:

```
Real time: 23.027 s
User time: 45.337 s
Sys. time: 0.047 s
Exit code: 0
```

---

`stdout` will read about this:

```
WARMUP: OpenMP thread[  0] instantiated as thread[  0]
WARMUP: OpenMP thread[  3] instantiated as thread[  3]
...
WARMUP: OpenMP thread[272] instantiated as thread[272]
my_routine():  thread[  0] START_TIME(           2078891848 )
my_routine():  thread[  2] START_TIME(           -528891186 )
...
my_routine():  thread[  2] ENDED_TIME(            635748478 ) sum =  1370488.801186
HOT RUN:    in thread[  2] my_routine() returned                          10.915321 ....
my_routine():  thread[  4] ENDED_TIME(          -1543969584 ) sum =  1370489.030301
HOT RUN:    in thread[  4] my_routine() returned                          11.133672 ....
my_routine():  thread[  1] ENDED_TIME(           -213996360 ) sum =  1370489.060176
HOT RUN:    in thread[  1] my_routine() returned                          11.158897 ....
...
my_routine():  thread[  0] ENDED_TIME(           -389214506 ) sum =  1370489.079366
HOT RUN:    in thread[270] my_routine() returned                          11.149798 ....
my_routine():  thread[  3] ENDED_TIME(           -586400566 ) sum =  1370489.125829
HOT RUN:    in thread[269] my_routine() returned                          11.091430 ....

OpenMP ver(201511)...finito
```

---

[mock-up source ( on TiO.run ):](https://tio.run/##rVRtb9owEP7eX3FqhZQUQjvoNg3KJLQitR8giAZt0jpFXuIEq4kT2Q4IVf3ryy4vJQmDiUm7DxGc7x7fPc@dnTg2fMdJ0wvGnSBxKdxGYdxdfQaAqyswTjBwMIMFFLyA@HIAhhfFlIcxGGb/DGGggpbKZRGC5@7izKUe4xSm42/2F3M5s9D3KbPs9j8irPvFZHz3mLnhJovofexVWG6U/MQywq0tokRhjqbn/pf8m1ssGFeeBuf1oAGAWglK3O@tvvsDHq3xwrKth@lEg1bv2gX9iZ93AJu0farsItTmSajplXejWIhQoA@ry8p6FEUuRvuRnSquNJmEgHHXw6qj3LxIgAZYNxKd4DcLKX/eVryVrnYb9Cr15ezAHe0Rwu3XbRRl6sMj5dbaev03Oiezu8ldg868ihG03r3vfvBO57aT59UrEVQlgmt1/2tF3jpiLmyICJcxNnjCMGM7dE25khBTgayHhDsU5DPdMO6jAIZkKikmqkEqQs/MuUEC9kwhJtsgIm4HtlQB5QjjUAkkCEpSDMalIlwxoljEJagIViTGhdm1dREL4ockax/RBKbSIB8CpKVkSGqNdagUr2aFFXPCyhkpQ9HRnJCGil/Hi@lyPgATy5nOGypWVVMXiKyf5QqywyIekCUrLiSMF2US4TsdcFZEwOUl/lnD/s5msBJhj3c/3Kk8bMqcCWoQIQj3aU0C2VywY3z/J1LvTQsWy9mg6L1Ban1rymFGdlv9G9wL6KL9ZTkaufrem7G7/ImXWq6p0Fqujpj4mDIVIa5tziczPHqTKE1/OfkTnr694Cm@4L8B)

```
#include <omp.h>   // ------------------------------------ compile flags: -fopenmp -O3
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_COUNT    999999999 
#define MAX_THREADS        272

double my_routine()
{
     printf( "my_routine():  thread[%3d] START_TIME( %20d )\n", omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_wtime() );
     double temp = omp_get_wtime(),
            sum  = 0;

     for ( int count = 0; count < MAX_COUNT; count++ )
     {
           sum += ( omp_get_wtime() - temp ); temp = omp_get_wtime();
     }
     printf( "my_routine():  thread[%3d] ENDED_TIME( %20d ) sum = %15.6f\n", omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_wtime(), sum );
     return( sum );
}

void warmUp() // -------------------------------- prevents performance skewing in-situ
{             // NOP-alike payload, yet enforces all thread-instantiations to happen
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads( MAX_THREADS )
    for ( int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++ )
         printf( "WARMUP: OpenMP thread[%3d] instantiated as thread[%3d]\n", i, omp_get_thread_num() );
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    omp_set_num_threads( MAX_THREADS ); warmUp(); // ---------- pre-arrange all threads

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for ( int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++ )
         printf( "HOT RUN:    in thread[%3d] my_routine() returned %34.6f ....\n", omp_get_thread_num(), my_routine() );

    printf( "\nOpenMP ver(%d)...finito", _OPENMP );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I execute on CentOS7 and a little confused with your guide. This is my NUMA-topology and htop monitor when I run application. You can see it only use 1 thread/core and with one thread also cannot archive 100%. **How I can use 4 threads/core or 100% 1 thread/core?** [image]  [image]